# CORE and Wireshark

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireshark

I use the CORE network emulator. I try to run Wireshark on one of the nodes via the terminal, but I get this error:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

On the host, I executed the following command:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:root
```

but it didn't help. What do I need to do to make Wireshark work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run Wireshark on node you need to run two commands:

1. on the host machine

   **xhost +**
2. in the node console:

   **DISPLAY=:0 wireshark**